# Why does this basic while loop written in c++ not work?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to learn C++ by tackling the Project Euler challanges. I am currently stuck on the first project where my while loop does not work. I have looked at it for over half an hour now but just can't see any issues with it, even though it's incredibly basic.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sum_3 = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while ( sum_3 < 1000 ) {
        sum_3 = sum_3 + (i * 3);
        i++;
        return sum_3, i;
   }

        std::cout << sum_3 << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I am trying to sum every number which is a multiple of 3 but smaller than 1000. I have re-written the program, entered print statements to try and troubleshoot it, but I'm just going around in circles now.

Comment: Why are you `return`ing some trash from the loop??? In order to _learn C++_, you first need to actually _learn_ how `while` loops work and much more. After you learn this, try dealing with these problems.

Comment: What do you think the `return` statement does?

Comment: "I'm just going around in circles". Because of the `return` statement, you're not. :)

Comment: @ForceBru, because if I don't apply what I learn immediately to something then I won't remember it. Certainly I will remember this more than by reading about while loops in a book. Thank you for both of your responses, I think I understand the return function now, I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: @EdwardHaigh _Overcomplicating_ hits it right twice. `return sum_3, i;` introducing the _comma operator_ is quite weird.

Comment: @ForceBru I really don't understand why you couldn't give a constructive response instead of belittling the OP.  After all, I believe everyone has to start learning somewhere, and if when someone asks for help they get insults that's not very encouraging.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  With a debugger, you would spot this in less time it took to write this post, publish it and wait for an answer.

Comment: @Phil, where did you see insults here? OP should just first _learn the basics of C++_ and only then he should try writing this code.

Answer (score 7):

The `return` keyword leaves the current function, not just the current scope.

```
    return sum_3, i;
```

doesn't do what you think it does, either. You can only `return` a single object. The reason the line compiles is that C++ has a `,` operator which evaluates the expression on the left, discards the result, and then evaluates the expression on the right. So

```
    return sum_3, i;
```

simply returns `i`.

Because the loop is in main, `return`ing also ends the program.

Your code should probably just look like this:

```
while ( sum_3 < 1000 ) {
    sum_3 = sum_3 + (i * 3);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Though in C++11 and with the proper return type for the function, `return {sum_3, i};` would properly return a constructed object holding those two values (and would result in a compilation error otherwise).

Comment: I completely misunderstood what 'return' did. I thought it returned the value from the while loop into the variables. Am I right in saying that return should only be used once in the main() function then?

Comment: And judging by the question text, the while condition should probably be `while(i * 3 < 1000)`.

Comment: @EdwardHaigh Only use `return` when you have reached a point where you wish to leave the current function. You could use it early in main to test some condition: e.g. `if (sum_3 > 10000) { cout << "sum_3 is too large. ending\n"; return 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You should not return unless you want to get off your function, in this case is the main function.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int sum_3 = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while ( sum_3 < 1000 ) {// I'd use a 'for' here, if I were you
        sum_3 += (i * 3); //is the same for sum_3 = sum_3 + (i * 3);
        i++;
   }

    std::cout << sum_3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What needs to be smaller than 1000? The total or the individual multiples of 3?

If what you want is the total to not exceed 1000, then just remove the line "return sum_3, i" and you're good to go.

If what you wanted was to sum all multiples of 3 that are also smaller than 1000 (but the total can exceed 1000) then you need to also change the while condition to "(i*3)<1000" instead of "sum_3<1000".